# If $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(1)\implies$ some $x_i$ is unit

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an unital commutative ring such that is local. I'm trying to prove

$$(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=(1)\implies \text{some}\ a_i\text{ is unit}$$

If $R$ is local this statement above is true?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You simply proved the contrapositive.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff oh, it's true, I will edit it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so if $R$ is maximal, the statement is true?

Comment: Maximal ideals are always proper. What do you mean by "$R$ is maximal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.  A ring is local iff the set of non units is an ideal, which would of course be maximal.  So if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are not units then they are all contained in the maximal ideal and hence the ideal they generate is contained in the maximal ideal also.

Of course this does not hold in a general ring.  Take say, $\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the ideal generated by $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I remarked that I proved the contrapositive.

Comment: Using your example, it's not possible, but if $R$ is local the statement is true?

Comment: Yes and your proof is correct.